# Question on conditional probability with extra condition

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In a population $40$% of the children have blue eyes and $60$% have green eyes.

Secondly (the extra condition), if a child that is randomly selected has blue eyes then the probability for each other brother or sister of this child to have blue eyes as well is $75$%.

---

a) In this population a family having $2$ children is selected. What is the probability that both children have green eyes?

b) In this population a family having $2$ children of which at least one has green eyes is selected. What is the probability that both children have green eyes?

---

My try: for simplicity let it be that we are dealing with e.g. $100$  families that have $2$ children. Let $x$ of them have $BB$ (i.e. two children with blue eyes) let $y$ of them have $GB$ and also $y$ have $BG$ (same probability as $GB$) and let $z$ have $GG$. Then there are $2x+4y+2z=200$ children of which $2x+2y$ have blue eyes and $2y+2z$ have green eyes. This tells us that $2x+2y=0.4\times200=80$ and $2y+2z=0.6\times200=120$.

But I am stuck here and would not be surprised if this is not the route I should take. Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I correct that we can not assume the entire population is made of two-person families (thought that might be a starting point)? I think we need to find the version of _the extra condition_ for green eyes, but I'm not sure we can solve this without knowing the family structure in the population.

Comment: I think the problem statement should be more precise. What is the precise selection process for these families? For example in b) do we first collect all families fitting the description and then make a random choice, or do we make a random choice among all families and it just so happens that it fits the description. We also need to know if we deliberately looked for 2-children families and whether there is anything special about 2-children families. Additionally, we need to know the probability of a sibling having green eyes if a child has green eyes.

Comment: @Shane You are correct. It is just an assumption *of me* to make things less complicated. I also wondered about the relevance of family structure. But in the question (asked on an exam) nothing was said about it.

Comment: @Vera Any further questions?

Answer (score 2):

I have the following two-way table (probabilities):

$$\begin{array}{|m{cm}|m{1cm}|}
\hline  &  \text{child blue eyes}  &\text{child green eyes}   \\ \hline \hline \hline\text{broth./sist. blue eyes}& 0.3 (x)&0.1 &0.4\\ \hline \text{broth./sist. green eyes}& 0.1 (y)&0.5&0.6 \\ \hline & 0.4 &0.6 &1 \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

If a child that is randomly selected has blue eyes then the probability for each other brother or sister of this child to have blue eyes as well is 75%.

Thus $0.75=\frac{x}{0.4}\Longrightarrow x=0.75\cdot 0.4=0.3$

And $y=0.4-0.3=0.1$

A sister/brother is a child, too. So they have the same (unconditonal) probability to have blue eyes/green eyes. Now it is easy to complete the table.

**Ad a)** The answer can be read off the table.

**Ad b)**

A: Event, that a family having 2 children of which at least one has green eyes.

B: Event, that both children of a family have green eyes.

It is asked for $P(B|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$

$P(A \cap B)=P(B)=0.5$ and $P(A)=0.1+0.1+0.5=0.7$.

Now it it easy to calculate $P(B|A)$.